# Set margin between UITableViewCell using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, margin

Is there a best way to set margin between **UITableViewCell**, i have one image and a label in table cell, i know this question can be marked as possible duplicate but i have searched a lot and the solution found almost everywhere was ;

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return yourArry.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

but problem is that when i tried the above code, the function **cellForRowAtIndexPath** returned **0** every time and ultimately the whole table was showing the same value in each cell. As i am new to IOS developing, i am unable to resolve this issue, any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolve it**, i just set the margin bottom (reset the constraints in AutoLayout) between the imageView and cell container like 10.5, now the imageView is not getting attached with the next cell.